# Recording with Scarlett 2i4 in Audacity (Mac)

Tags: production, audio, mixer, audio-editing, music-production-station

I want to record audio into Audacity via Scarlett 2i4 audio interface (connected to a Behringer DDM4000) on Mac, but I does not show up in the drop down list, I only see the integrated microfone, nevertheless It appears as a MIDI device.

In OBS it works fine

[image]

[image]

Comment: Audio interface connected to a mixer?  As far as I know, the audio interface connects via USB and require a driver, and mixers don't accept that kind of connection.  Can you clarify?

Comment: out of   Behringer DDM4000 -> In Scarlett 2i4 audio interface